# How does current travel if disconnected from a voltage source part of RL circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current

Specifically, this RL circuit confuses me. RL circuit with SPDT switch If the switch in a circuit is connected to a voltage source for a long period of time (t < 0), and then disconnected from the voltage source at t = 0, how will the current behave? My goal is to determine i1, i2, i3 after the switch is moved (t > 0). However, I want to understand how the current behaves in this situation first.[image: RL circuit with SPDT switch]

I know that current travels in the path of least resistance. I assume that because this is an RL circuit, current will build up in the resistor over time.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Regardless, you mean the switch moves from position 1 to position 2 at t=0, correct? Just solve for the current through the inductors at t<0.  Assume the current through an inductor does not instantly change.  Now solve for the current for t>0.

Comment: This sounds like homework, so please attempt a solution and add that to your question.

Comment: Current does not "travel in the path of least resistance".  It travels in all possible paths, with lower resistance paths carrying more current than higher resistance paths.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

> *how will the current behave?*

It will continue to flow in the same directions as shown by \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$. But, due to the switch changing over, a combined current will flow through the path indicated by \$i_3\$ and, both of those current will dwindle down to zero (as dictated by their respective L/R time constants).

Additionally, there is no interaction between \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$.

> *I know that current travels in the path of least resistance.*

That is untrue. Take a 10 Ω resistor in parallel with a 9 Ω resistor and ask yourself if current only flows through the 9 Ω resistor when a voltage is applied.

Answer (score 1):

When the switch is in position 1 the LEDs are both off as they are reverse polarised. When switching to the 2 position, both LEDs will flash. In this way you can immediately understand what the directions of the currents are.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Franc - Hi, I appreciate you're trying to help. However there are three major problems with this style of answer: (a) As you are generating the formulas (formulae) elsewhere and just posting images here, they are effectively invisible for anyone using screen readers as there is no real text. (b) The "text" in the image is too small to be easily readable. (c) The images are "landscape orientation". If you must use images (preferably don't - see point (a)), it would be better to post "longer" images instead of "wider" ones. That might also make it easier for you to make the font bigger. Thanks!

Comment: I corrected it, I hope it is readable or at least understandable.

Comment: Franc - Thanks. I didn't mean to suggest a *single* long image (there were 3 or 4 landscape images before, and each one could have been made into 2 portrait format images). That's so unusual that I think some people (e.g. trying to view it on a phone) will struggle. But at least the "text" is now large enough to see, thanks! (Your use of the site in this way is so unusual that I don't pretend to know how best to minimise all the problems. My previous comment was really just pointing out that there *are* problems. I don't know all the solutions :( Thanks for the improvement anyway :)